# Flickering/vanishing header with position:fixed in iOS 11

Tags: ios, css, viewport, css-transforms, ios11

I have a header with following CSS:

```
.header{
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1320px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

I have infinite scroll in the container of the content. In iOS 11, when I scroll the header vanishes for a second and then comes back again.

I have tried the following fixes:

1. `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`
2. `transform: translateZ(0)`
3. `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;`
4. I have added `viewport-fit="cover"` and `viewport-fit="contain"` in the meta viewport tag too. As suggested [here](https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/).
5. Also none of the child elements of header have `position: fixed;` in their CSS.
6. I have tried above solutions by adding `left: 0;` too.
7. Another solution suggested that I have tried is adding `-webkit-overflow: hidden;` to the body of the page.
8. I also tried adding `overflow-x:hidden;` to html tag of the page.

All the above solutions have not worked.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try adding `overflow-x: hidden` and `position: relative` to a wrapping element of `.header`?

I don't know if it's possible in your case since you only shared the `.header` CSS class so you may not have a parent to apply it to but I found that this answer [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-fixed-position-element-disappears-during-transition-on-mobile-browsers/8960/2) seems to work. I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I fought with this recently and basically iOS doesn't like `position: fixed` combined with scrolling.

`transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` seems to work on iOS 12.x.x but causes my header to flicker when scrolling (which is another issue).

I ended up having:

`position: absolute`